# Multiple delete querie fail when 2/3 matches are found

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i am currently working with 3 tables where 1 querie delete all rows with matching id's, the problem is sometimes the third table t3 does not contain any data and therefore the whole script breaks.

Is there anything i can do to let this querie delete from the 2 out of 3 tables even tho there is no match in the third t3 table ?

```
DELETE t1, t2, t3
 FROM table1 t1
  table2 t2
  table3 t3
 WHERE t1.column1 = 1
 AND t2.column2 = 1
 AND t3.column3 = 1 // When this one does not have any matches the whole script fails
```

A simple but in my opinion 'weak' method of doing this is to split it up into 3 different queries but thats all a shame isent it?

Comment: Extract a [mcve], please.

Comment: I would actually recommend the "weak" method. Seems cleaner

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt how is this not a minimal example? i cant make it any lesser code or clearer?

Comment: It's not complete, thus also not verifiable. Also, if the same problem occurred with two or one table, it wouldn't be minimal. It's your job to determine that first, without it the site rules explicitly say that your question is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

In your case, you want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
DELETE t1, t2, t3
    FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
         table2 t2
         ON t1.column = t2.column LEFT JOIN
         table3 t3
         ON t1.column = t3.column
    WHERE t1.column1 = 1;
```

This will work for missing rows in `table2` and `table3`.  If there are no matching rows in `table1`, then nothing will be deleted.

Comment: This seems like the correct answer to the specific question being asked. However, I would say that this problem would likely go away with normalization and cascading delete on foreign keys. Would have to know more about the schema to be sure.

Comment: @IsaacFife i will look into cascading delete and normalization